# Free Floating, Customized, Toolbox for PowerPoint 2010 and above

Tags: vba, customization, powerpoint, toolbox

in order to be faster while creating slides in PowerPoint (PP) 2010 or above 
I want to create a toolbox. This toolbox - that I want to be able to move around within the PP-Window as needed, from left to right, from top to bottom - will have about 30 icons. Each icon will have one function. Most fuctions are typical PP-Functions such as "Align shapes right" etc. Put some will be self programmed functions for which I will create an icon.

Here is my question: How do I best realize the toolbox (not a ribbon that only stays at the top!)? Is there a given functionality in PP 2010 or above to do so? Or what is the best way? As a newbie I don't have a clou what I'm searching for.

And second question: In a long run this toolbox - or at least the custom functions in it - should be loaded at PP start-up from a server for easier maintanance if used by many clients. what is the best way/procedure/architecture to do so?

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How do I best realize the toolbox

As a UserForm.  And when you .Show the user form, show it modelessly, which means it'll stay visible until you close it but won't block other operations.

> > In a long run this toolbox - or at least the custom functions in it - should be loaded at PP start-up from a server for easier maintanance if used by many clients. what is the best way/procedure/architecture to do so?

The best way to do this is not to do it.  PowerPoint will bite you.  Instead, consider creating the toolbox as a PPT add-in, installing it on each PC, then if need be, have the user's logon script check for a newer version of the add-in on the server, copy it to the local computer if so.